# export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, webpack

**Код из main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from 'pages/App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: a => a(App)
})
```

**Код из App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!profile">Необходимо авторизоваться через <a href="/login">Google</a></div>
    <div v-else>
      <div>{{ profile.name }}&nbsp;<a href="/logout">Выйти</a></div>
      <!--  <messages-list :messages="messages"/> -->
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
     data() {
       return{
         messages: frontendData.messages,
         profile: frontendData.profile
       }
     }
 }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sarafan",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.30",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**Ошибка**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять что не так, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Смог исправить путём исправления кода в main.js на следующий:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from 'pages/App.vue'

export const eventBus = createApp(App)

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Буду признателен если кто-нибудь объяснит в чём-таки была ошибка

Comment: Здесь не принято задавать новые вопросы в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в новой версии vue нет дефолтного экспорта.

Поэтому можно импортировать конкретные методы `import { createApp } from 'vue'`.

Или использовать такой способ импорта `import * as Vue from 'vue'`

Небольшой пример:

```
import * as Vue from ‘vue';

import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store’';

Vue.createApp(App).use(store).mount( ‘#app' );
```